# VS2012 Install Shield project building using TFS build definition

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a `VS2012 sln` which includes an install shield installer project.
If I build the solution/projects manually via solution explorer everything builds fine. 
However when using the TFS build definitions i get the following error:

`C:\Builds\1\<NAME>\<Build_Definition_Name>\Sources\InstallSetup\InstallSetup.isproj (29)`: The imported project

"`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2012SpringLimited\InstallShield.targets`" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Can someone please help with this?

Info:

```
Using VS 2012
    OS - Win 7 x64 Pro
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install InstallShield on the machine on which you are running the build.

Answer (score 0):

In-case someone is facing the same issue, I was able to solve it by reading what Flexera mentioned on their website: [Link](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield20helplib/Content/helplibrary/TFS-Overview.htm)

Brief description: in build definition, process tab, make sure the MSBuild Platform is targeting x86.

I too had 64bit Windows (8.1) running and Team Foundation Server 2013 Express.